# Why does a list of a union of two types not expand to a union of lists of these two types?

Tags: python, list, union, mypy, typing

I have been struggling a bit with `mypy` when combining `List` and `Union` types. I know the answer now, but would like to document my findings on here. The question is: Why does a list of a union of two types not expand to union of lists of these two types? So, why are the two aliases `RepeatedDataType1` and `RepeatedDataType2` below not equivalent?

```py
from typing import List, Union

DataType = Union[str, int]

RepeatedDataType1 = List[DataType]
# (type alias) RepeatedDataType1: Type[List[str | int]]
RepeatedDataType2 = Union[List[str], List[int]]
# (type alias) RepeatedDataType2: Type[List[str]] | Type[List[int]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me a little time to understand what was happening. The answer to this question is that these two types are really different because a list of a union of two types can also contain mixed types.

The following code demonstrates the issue:

```py
repeated_data1: RepeatedDataType1 = ["a", 1]  # OK
repeated_data2: RepeatedDataType2 = ["a", 1]  # Incompatible types in assignment
# (expression has type "List[object]", variable has type "Union[List[str], List[int]]")
```